# Are camels really a problem when traveling by car in the Negev?

Tags: driving, safety, israel

In Negev area of Israel along most roads you see signs with warnings about camels that can enter the road. I've done way over 1000 kilometers and I have not see single camel there.

Are camels really a threat and something you should be checking for when driving in Negev?

Comment: Are camels even real? Have not seen any...

Comment: Camels are real, I have seen them.  Whether there are any in this location is another question that I cannot answer.

Comment: Having seen camels in Australia, I bet that when they do get onto the road you will not be happy to drive into them.

Comment: Being from a country where camels is a real thing and a real threat to drivers in highways, camel-related accidents are nasty and death is almost guaranteed to the driver and the other passenger sitting at the front. They have long legs, causing the camel to enter the car with its full weight, something like [this](https://cdn.al-ain.com/archive/news-image/a-camel-stuck-in-a-car.jpg). For more photos, search google for "حادث جمل" and [see](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%AB+%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%84)..

Comment: @NeanDerThal: this is really terrifying...

Comment: @NeanDerThal So, when it comes to driving, camels are the moose of the desert?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany exactly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, although somewhat rare, they do happen. And most importantly, because of the weight and structure of a camel, they are usually deadly.

Some examples from recent years (all sources in Hebrew):

- [October 1<sup>st</sup>, 2019](http://mynetbeersheva.co.il/%d7%97%d7%93%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%aa/%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%9e%d7%94-%d7%91%d7%a0%d7%92%d7%91-7-%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%98%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%a0%d7%a4%d7%a6%d7%a2%d7%95-%d7%91%d7%a8%d7%94%d7%98-%d7%97%d7%a9%d7%93-%d7%9c%d7%a8%d7%a6%d7%97-%d7%91%d7%9c%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%94-433813/7): 2 injured in a collision with a camel on route 316 at the entrance to Hura, the driver died in the hospital a week and a half later.
- [October 1<sup>st</sup>, 2019](https://www.mako.co.il/hix-nature/4ac9a3b9d6b54310/Article-07a9192db1c8d61027.htm): 2 people injured and 4 camels dead in a collision between a car and a heard of camels on route 40 in the northern Negev. A quote from the article talking about the dangers of such collisions, quoting Adam Sela a paramedic that treated the injured:

> It's really a miracle, I don't remember accidents with camels where the passengers stayed alive. ... In most cases, they are either killed or seriously injured. They were saved from certain death. Hitting a camel weighing several tons can end in death. You just need to look at their car and understand how this could have ended in a tragedy.

> "זה ממש נס. אני לא זוכר תאונות עם גמלים שהנוסעים יצאו בחיים", אומר ל-mako פרמדיק איחוד והצלה, אדם סלע, "במרבית המקרים הם נהרגים או נפצעים באורח קשה. הם ניצלו ממוות בטוח. פגיעה בגמל ששוקל כמה טונות יכולה להסתיים במוות. רק צריך להסתכל על המכונית שלהם ותבין עד כמה זה יכול היה להסתיים בטרגדיה נוראית".

- [January 13<sup>th</sup>, 2018](https://news.walla.co.il/item/3127804): 13 years old boy killed and 8 injured in a collision between two cars and a camel next to Nafkha Penitentiary.
- [September 4<sup>th</sup>, 2008](https://www.makorrishon.co.il/nrg/online/1/ART1/782/494.html): a driver is killed in a collision with a camel next to Yeruham.

Comment: These are not the only cases, there are more cases, it's just an example.